# Windows mobile, how do I receive callbacks from the camera?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am developing an C# app in WM 6. I am using CameraCaptureDialog to open the camera.

I would need to receive callbacks from the camera, I know this method is not implemented by CameraCaptureDialog.

I would need for Windows Mobile, sth similar to this method in Android:

camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(previewCallback);

Do you know any other library I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The CameraCaptureDialog isn't going to be of much use at all. To get access to the camera on a WinMo device, you need to use a DirectShow filtergraph. There's a [reasonably good article on CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/bitmap/capturing/article.php/c12327/) that covers WinMo specifically.